# C++ Textfiles Not Working Now?

Tags: c++, text-files

**Edit:** solved...using the same ifstream for multiple files is apparently not a good idea.

I just bought a new laptop, and having transfered my C++ project to the new computer, I'm suddenly having an issue with reading text files from Code::Blocks...I'm not sure why.

The old laptop ran a 32 bit OS whereas the new one is 64 bit. I don't know if that would affect anything.

Here's the section of code that is no longer working:

```
ifstream myfile;
//edit: a different file is read here, in exactly the same manner as below
//when I comment it out, the following section works as it's meant to...
//what am I doing wrong that they won't work successively

myfile.open("version.txt");

if (myfile.is_open()) {
    out("This message displays...");
    //OK so apparently 'eofbit' is thrown here...but the file has content in it?
    while (myfile.good()) {
        out("This message doesn't, when it should...");
        getline(myfile,version_info);
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

edit: 'out' is just a custom script to display a message, btw.

Comment: Is the code compiled for 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: @Preet Sangha Well I rebuilt the whole project on the 64bit laptop so I assume that. It works on the 32bit laptop though, and everything else works on the 64bit laptop, just not files...

Comment: @keith.layne I know the code is fine, because I've been using it for months on the other laptop. If there's something to debug, I don't know what it is. That's why I've come to you guys ;)

Comment: If `myfile.good()` is false, then at least one of `eofbit`, `badbit`, or `failbit` flags is set. `failbit` gets set when an I/O operation fails, so since you don't try that, it must be one of the other flags.

Comment: eofbit triggered. Does that mean the file is empty? It's not though...

Comment: Perhaps it is not finding the file, but it creates a file? I don't think it should do that. Could it be opening a file in another directory than you expect?

Comment: I've done a search, all of the version.txt files except for the 'correct' one have not been touched.

Comment: Updated OP, possibly found the problem but not sure what's causing it...

Comment: Do you mean you were opening another file with the same variable `myfile` then you opened `version.txt` after that?

Comment: Yes, but there were no problems in the past so I assumed that was OK..? I will try using a different ifstream for the second file...urg...yeah that worked. I don't know why it was fine on my other laptop; thank you!

Comment: Not the current problem. But you should note that `while (myfile.good())` is nearly always wrong. It is considered an anti-pattern for reading a file.

Comment: @Matthew I wasn't meaning to suggest that your program was wrong, but an interactive debugging session can show you in real time what is actually going on...without modifying your code that you're already pretty confident in.

Comment: @Loki Astari Hmm, noted. I only use that method as it's what cplusplus.com uses.

Comment: @Matthew: Well I can't say I think highly of cplusplus.com lots of incorrect stuff on there (but it seems popular). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/14065

Comment: My question was what platform is the code compiled for?

Answer (score 0):

try using `myFile.rdstate()` to determine what is causing the error see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/rdstate/)

Comment: Oh wait...I got eofbit to trigger.

Comment: well I assume you can open it in another editor so perhaps try create a new empty file copy paste its contents and try open that new file.